# awk command in perl scripts getting error

Tags: bash, perl

I am running the below code in my perl script.

```
my $record = `awk -F'[:;]' '$1 == "Amy"' data.txt`;
```

However, it's giving me the error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>>  == <<< 
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: untested, `my ($record) = map scalar(qx($_)), q(awk -F'[:;]' '$1 == "Amy"' data.txt);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to escape the $ sign:

```
my $record = `awk -F'[:;]' '\$1 == "Amy"' data.txt`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `awk` in backticks from perl is a pretty nasty thing to do. `perl` replicates pretty much all the same functionality - all you do is introduce additional overhead, inefficiency and quoting problems (like you've got in your example).

Why not instead:

```
open ( my $input, '<', 'data.txt' ) or die $!;
my ($record) = grep { (split /[:;]/)[0] eq 'Amy' } <$input>;
```

This replicates what you're doing, but you could instead do something altogether more elegant like:

```
my %person;
while ( <$input> ) { 
    chomp;
    my ( $name, @fields ) = split /[;:]/; 
    $person{$name} = \@fields; 
}
```

And then:

```
print join " ", @{$person{'Amy'}},"\n";
```